# Unsuccessful connection to MySql using Dapper Framework in .NET 6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have created a WEB MVC view project with .NET 6 environment and I am getting an error when I try to connect to the database.
I introduced the package MySql.Data (8.1.0).

`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacketAsync(Boolean execAsync)`

Below are the mysql configuration parameters from the appsettings.json file.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionString": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=test;user=root;password=root;"
}
```

Here is the Program.cs code

```
MySqlDBHelper.DB_CONNECTION_STRING = app.Configuration["ConnectionString"];
```

I am sure that my database account password is not set incorrectly

I have tried DEBUG
to make sure the conn is getting the DB_CONNECTION_STRING data correctly.
Here is the Add method for the controller

```
        [HttpGet("Add")]
        public object Add(string FileName, string FilePath,string ImageUrl)
        {

            var sql = "INSERT INTO image_info (FileName, FilePath, ImageUrl) VALUES (@FileName, @FilePath, @ImageUrl)";


            using var conn = MySqlDBHelper.GetSqlConnection();

            conn.Open();
            var result = conn.Execute(sql, new { FileName, FilePath, ImageUrl });
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no C code in your question. Please take a few seconds to verify that you add related tags to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**

Mysql8.0+ has updated the password encryption method compared with the old version.

Open the command, enter mysql>, and then enter

```
mysql> select user,host,plugin from mysql.user;
```

You can see that the plugin (plug-in) format has been updated to caching_sha2_password, so we only need to change to the old version mysql_native_password:

ALTER USER 'root'@'here is the name under host such as localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password';

Remember to refresh the command `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after the modification; (refresh permissions)